# What is a word/term for rendering highlighted text as normal text

Tags: antonyms

We can definitely "Highlight" a section of text. But is there a word or a phrase that defines taking highlighted text and, um, de-highlighting it? "low-light" doesn't seem to capture what I'm talking about.

Comment: Merge with the normal, un-highlight, homogenize, etc.

Comment: Unmark, clear formatting.

Comment: Remove highlighting.

Comment: *unhighlight*, *dehighlight*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two uses of "highlight" that have different senses. One use is to physically change the background color of a bit of text, which the Oxford English Dictionary defines as "To make visually prominent." In that case the comment suggestions of "clear formatting" or "un-highlight" would work.

The more general use of "highlight" is defined in the OED as "To bring into prominence; to draw attention to." In that case the opposite would be to "deemphasize," which the OED defines as "To remove emphasis from, or reduce emphasis on."